# how to write C# lamba queries more efficiently

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there any way to shorten these three lambda expressions? Right now I need three steps to get the result.

First I look up all the targets who belong to 'someone'. Then I look in the link table for all the projectIds who belong to these targets. The final lambda returns all the projects by their id.

I can't help but think that there's a more efficient way but I can't seem to find it...

```
public async Task<List<Project>> GetProjectsFromSomeone(string someone) {
    var targetIds = from target in Context.Targets
                     where target.Someone.ToLower().Contains(someone.ToLower())
                     select target.Id;

    var projectIds = from pt in Context.ProjectTargets
                 where targetIds.Any(id  => id == pt.TargetId)
                 select pt.ProjectId;

    var projects = from prj in Context.Projects
                where projectIds.Any(id => id == prj.Id)
                select prj;

    return await projects.ToListAsync(); 
}

public class ProjectTarget
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TargetId { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Target Target { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Someone { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, the third one is useless if you just change the second from `select pt.ProjectId` to `select pt.Project`

Comment: Even though you create your query in 3 steps you're only doing one call to the DB.  You could rewrite it to one query statement with navigation properties or joins, but there's a good change it would have the same run time.  So I guess it depends on what you mean by efficient.

Comment: Throwing this out there, don't .toLower() for string comparisons if you can help it.  .ToUpper() or .ToUpperInvariant() is preferred, bonus if you also use CultureInfo to sharpen the definition of your match.

Comment: @CDove Using `ToUpperInvariant` or the overload with CultureInfo would not work because this is EF that is translated into SQL.  It's likely not needed at all as most DBs usually have a collation that is case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Linq joins`. Linq will take care of joins and where conditions.

```
public async Task<List<Project>> GetProjectsFromSomeone(string someone) 
{    
    var projects = from target in Context.Targets
                join pt in Context.ProjectTargets on target.Id equals pt.TargetId
                join prj in Context.Projects on pt.ProjectId equals prj.Id
                where target.Someone.ToLower().Contains(someone.ToLower())
                select prj;
    return await projects.ToListAsync(); 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP was doing a `Contains` not an `Equals`.  Also you cannot control the case sensitivity of a EF query as it's translated to SQL and that will be determined by the DBs collation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the join queries.

```
from P in Context.Projects
join PT in Context.ProjectTargets on P.Id equals PT.id
join T in Context.Targets on PT.TargetId equals T.id
  .Select(m => new
  {
      //select the fields which you want select
  });
```